# Is the Hadoop read-only default configuration file core-default.xml read at startup?

Tags: hadoop

Is the file described in the documentation as a read-only configuration file, src/core/core-default.xml, used by Hadoop at startup? Some of the docs say to copy this file to conf/core-site.xml and make changes and some say to include only those properties being changed. If the latter is the case, it seems the core-default.xml file is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

core-default.xml is loaded first and then core-site.xml is overlayed on that. core-site.xml will only contain the values that need to be changed from the default.

See the resources section at the top of: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

Just another information which may be interesting here: If you use the constructor of YarnConfiguration yarn-default.xml and yarn-site.xml are read additionally.